# Script affecting the div not linked to it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using this script to hide the header whenever I scroll down and show it again when I scroll up.

```
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("header").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header").style.top = "-55px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

It's working fine.

But the same thing is  happening to one more div whose code is given below:

```
<div class="pricing">
           <h2>Our Plans</h2>
<button type="button" name="button" class="commonBtn" id="bookBtn"> Buy Now</button>
</div>
<div id="book">
           <div id="closeBtn">
             x
           </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
         var bookBtn = document.getElementById("bookBtn");
         var book = document.getElementById("book");
         book.style.bottom = "-1000px";
           bookBtn.onclick = function(){
             if (book.style.bottom=="-1000px") {
               book.style.bottom="-100px";
             }
         var closeBtn = document.getElementById("closeBtn");
               closeBtn.onclick = function(){
                 if (book.style.bottom=="-100px"){
                   book.style.bottom="-1000px";
                 }
               }
           }
           </script>
```

This book div is also showing a part of it when scrolled up and hiding when scrolled down.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Thanks For Your Help In Advance.

PS: Its happening only in mobile devices. In Chrome DEV TOOLS also its working fine.

The Header Div

```
<header class="header" id="header">
      <nav class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Plans</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Offers</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
     <li><div class="custom-control custom-switch">
       <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="darkSwitch" />  </ul>
 </nav>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="masthead">
          <div class="mastheadLeft">
            <img src="image/logo.png" class="headerLogo">
          </div>
          <div class="mastheadRight">
            <div id="menuBtn">
                &#9776;
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

CSS For Header and Book div.

```
#book{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -1000px;
  background: #0079e3;
  transition: 2s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to use Percentage (%) or Viewport height/width (vw/vh) instead of px in your case.

Comment: You need share some more of your code

Comment: @Vova I have tried with ```%```also. Infact at first i used % then I saw that thing happening and thought ```px``` may help.

Comment: @gpl what kind of more code should i share?

Comment: @SubhodipRoy your css and header div

Comment: @gpl I have added the css and header code. Please inform if i need to post anything more. And please up-vote the question if you find it interesting.

Comment: @SubhodipRoy you missing `</div>` of  `<div class="custom-switch">`. Also missing `</li>` of the parent list-item

Comment: @SubhodipRoy how and where you invoking your first javascript? For me your 2nd script working fine and first script doing nothing. Afcourse because idk where you invoked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with using pixels and percentage. The problem has been solved by using `vh` instead of `px` and `%`.

The Correct Code Is Given Below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         var bookBtn = document.getElementById("bookBtn");
         var book = document.getElementById("book");
         book.style.bottom = "-100vh";
           bookBtn.onclick = function(){
             if (book.style.bottom=="-100vh") {
               book.style.bottom="-100px";
             }
         var closeBtn = document.getElementById("closeBtn");
               closeBtn.onclick = function(){
                 if (book.style.bottom=="-100px"){
                   book.style.bottom="-100vh";
                 }
               }
           }
           </script>

#book{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -1000px;
  background: #0079e3;
  transition: 2s;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

This is correct javascript and css code. The Problem was in these two parts only rest all are fine.